# Estimate Power spectral density using Discrete wavelet transform form pycwt

Tags: python, power-spectral-density, wavelet, discrete-wavelet-transform

I want to estimate the Power spectral density using Discrete wavelet transform and a Morlet Wavelet. Bellow you can find the function I am using. Any comments or suggestions on wether or not the following code is correct?

```
import pycwt as wavelet


mother_wave_dict = {
    'gaussian': wavelet.DOG(),
    'paul': wavelet.Paul(),
    'mexican_hat': wavelet.MexicanHat()
}

def trace_PSD_wavelet(x, dt, dj,  mother_wave='morlet'):
    """
    Method to calculate the  power spectral density using wavelet method.
    Parameters
    ----------
    x : array-like
        the components of the field to apply wavelet tranform
    dt: int
        the sampling time of the timeseries
    dj: determines how many scales are used to estimate wavelet coeff
    
        (e.g., for dj=1 -> 2**numb_scales 
    mother_wave: str
        The main waveform to transform data.
        Available waves are:
        'gaussian':
        'paul': apply lomb method to compute PSD
        'mexican_hat':
    Returns
    -------
    db_x,db_y,db_zz: array-like
        component coeficients of th wavelet tranform
    freq : list
        Frequency of the corresponding psd points.
    psd : list
        Power Spectral Density of the signal.
    psd : list
        The scales at which wavelet was estimated
    """
    

    if mother_wave in mother_wave_dict.keys():
        mother_morlet = mother_wave_dict[mother_wave]
    else:
        mother_morlet = wavelet.Morlet()
        
    N                       = len(x)

    db_x, _, freqs, _, _, _ = wavelet.cwt(x, dt,  dj, wavelet=mother_morlet)

     
    # Estimate trace powerspectral density
    PSD = (np.nanmean(np.abs(db_x)**2, axis=1))*( 2*dt)
    
    # Also estimate the scales to use later
    scales = ((1/freqs)/dt)#.astype(int)
    
    return db_x, freqs, PSD, scales
```

Comment: I've never heard of a wavelet-based Power Spectral Density...

Comment: You can take a look here https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/physics/research/cfsa/people/sandrac/lectures/lecturenotes_wavelets.pdf

Comment: Interesting! You should add that to your question for reference!